# Terminate outer map function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to terminate the map function when the if condition passes

```
dataset.Categories.map(function (item) {
    if(Object.keys(item)[0] == current_category){
        return false;  
    }
    else
        category_position++;
});
```

Here dataset is an object. The map function runs the entire length even if the condition passes.

Comment: Afaik you can't stop it. You could just shortcircuit.

Comment: @Sirko Can u elaborate?

Comment: can u provide an example of your variable - dataset ?

Comment: So, this your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27754286/1169519) was actually posted due to a misunderstanding of how `Array.map()` works?

Comment: @Teemu I initially thought that the problem was with the comparison

Comment: Why are you even using `.map()` for this purpose? You're not mapping anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you really wanted to use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
dataset.Categories.some(function (item) {
    if (Object.keys(item)[0] == current_category) {
        return true; // this will end the `some`
    }
    ++category_position;
});
```

---

Also, your test may be better written in the form

```
if (item.hasOwnProperty(current_category)) { // etc
```

as this avoids issues involving the order of keys multiple on an *Object*

Answer (score 1):

Something before the your actual question:

- As you do not create a new array, you might want to use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- I can't remember to see anything about these iterator functions guarantying the order, in which the elements are processed.

That beeing said to fix your code, I would introduce a variable to shortcircuit (as afaik those iterator functions can not be canceled):

```
var done = false,
    category_position = 0;
dataset.Categories.map(function (item) {
  if( done ) {
    return;
  } 

  if(Object.keys(item)[0] == current_category){
    done = true 
  } else {
    category_position += 1;
  }
});
```

Besides that, I think, that a mere `for` loop would be best for you here:

```
var category_position;
for( category_position=0; category_position<dataset.Categories.length; category_position++ ) {
  if(Object.keys(dataset.Categories[ category_position ])[0] == current_category){
    break;
  } 
}
```

Comment: you need to replace i by category_position.

Comment: Regarding your point about the order the iteration functions process, in fact both `.forEach()` and `.map()` definitely process elements in ascending index order (skipping elements that don't exist). If they didn't they'd be a lot less useful, plus their own implementations would be much less straightforward.